# How to reset textinputformat.record.delimiter to its default value within hive cli / beeline?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

Setting `textinputformat.record.delimiter` to a non-default value, is useful for loading multi-row text, as shown in the demo below.
However, I'm failing to set this parameter back to its default value without exiting the cli and reopen it.

None of the following options worked (nor some other trials)

```
set textinputformat.record.delimiter='\n';
set textinputformat.record.delimiter='\r';
set textinputformat.record.delimiter='\r\n';
set textinputformat.record.delimiter='
';

reset;
```

Any thought?

Thanks

#### Demo

```
create table mytable (mycol string);
insert into mytable select concat('Hello',unhex('A'),'world');    
select concat('>>>',mycol,'<<<') as mycol from mytable;
```

NewLine is interpreted is record delimiter, causing the insert of 2 records

```
+-------------+
|    mycol    |
+-------------+
| >>>Hello<<< |
| >>>world<<< |
+-------------+
```

---

```
set textinputformat.record.delimiter='\0';

truncate table mytable;
insert into mytable select concat('Hello',unhex('A'),'world');    
select concat('>>>',mycol,'<<<') as mycol from mytable;
```

The whole text was inserted as a single record

```
+----------+
|  mycol   |
+----------+
| >>>Hello |
| world    |
| <<<      |
+----------+
```

---

Trying to change the delimiter back to newline

```
set textinputformat.record.delimiter='\n';

truncate table mytable;
insert into mytable select concat('Hello',unhex('A'),'world');    
select concat('>>>',mycol,'<<<') as mycol from mytable;
```

Still get the same results

```
+----------+
|  mycol   |
+----------+
| >>>Hello |
| world    |
| <<<      |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the "textinputformat.record.delimiter" variable state? Was it really changed? You could do it calling `set textinputformat.record.delimiter` without any value. 
 If it was changed, but not works, you could definitely create issue in the issue tracker. As a workaround for setting delimiter param back to default value, you could try `RESET` command. It would **reset ALL properties to default values**, though this solution could be unacceptable for your case.

Comment: Yes I did and it seemed to be changed. You can see the `reset` in the list of "None of the following options worked".

Answer (score 1):

use unicode alt+A or  \u0001 as delimer.

Comment: SOH is not  LF nor CR and it does not make sense in anyway, since this is the default field delimiter.